# django fails to boot: ImportError: No module named domreg

Tags: django

I had a fully working site on django for a long time but one day it unexpectedly crashed and I got this error in supervisord log.
`ImportError: No module named domreg`

A fulltext search for "domreg" returns no results in my project folder and I don't remember even using this module.

I have no idea how to debug this. Please help.

Comment: domreg is part of python xml lib. https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Lib/xml/dom/domreg.py. What's your python version?

Comment: yes, I've googled it. python 2.7

Comment: Do you have a file called `domreg.py` in your django project?

Comment: Nope.
locate domreg
/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/domreg.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/domreg.pyc
but I use virtualenvs